# Can POD-structs be initialized using named attributes in a portable way in C++?

Tags: c++, gcc, portability, clang

I am trying to initialize a struct using named attributes in a way that is compatible both with GCC 4.3.4 and Clang 2.9.

```
struct A {
  unsigned int x;
};

// GCC: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
A a = {
  .x = 0xdeadbeef;
};

// Clang: error: use of GNU old-style field designator extension [-Werror,-Wgnu-designator]
A a = {
  x : 0xdeadbeef;
};
```

I cannot add *-Wno-gnu-designator* to *CXXFLAGS* because then GCC will refuse to build since it does not know that flag. I cannot use an initialization list without naming attributes because if the API changes we are going to have serious issues.

The solution I need has to conform to the C++ standard while retaining the fact that if new attributes appear in the struct they should be uninitialized (or preferably NULL). The structs are third party and I cannot alter them in any way.

Comment: I'm not sure that targeting two specific versions of specific toolchains counts as "portable".

Comment: "The solution I need has to conform to the C++ standard" - that's a problem then, since none of this is standard C++ yet. C++03 doesn't have initialization by named members, and GCC 4.3.4 doesn't have much C++0x in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot name the values, just give them in order.

```
A a = { 42 };
```

If new fields are added **at the end** of the struct, they will be zeroed.

Comment: Sadly there is no guarantee from the vendor that they will add them at the end.

Comment: @DavidHolm: This is why you need a proper versioning system.

Comment: You could perhaps deal with the order issue by writing a function `A make_A(unsigned int x) { A a = { 0 }; a.x = x; return a; }`. Now you can portably write `A a = make_A(0xdeadbeef);`, and if the vendor adds a member before `x` it is zero-initialized. You can then add it to `make_A` as a default parameter at the end, so the order of params is the order they were added, not the order in the struct. But you're no longer using named members in the initializer expression as requested, so I don't know whether this is acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
#if THIS_IS_GCC
  #define INIT_ATTR(x,y) x : y;
#elif THIS_IS_LLVM
  #define INIT_ATTR(x,y) .x=y;
#else
  #error Can't do it :/
#endif

A a = {
  INIT_ATTR(x,0xdeadbeef)
};
```

However this is really not standard C++.

Is anything wrong with :

```
A a;
a.x = y;
```

Comment: It's not standard English, either.

Comment: @DavidHolm You're complaining that you want code that's cross-compiler compatible, adherent to standards, and now _clean enough that others will like it_.  I'm sorry man, you need to order your priorities.  Sometimes not all constraints can be satisfied simultaneously.  That's life.